# attach excel inline in the email message using JavaMail

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-mail, mime-types, multipart

I have a requirement to send an email with message body including a table from excel worksheet. Any ideas on how to acheive this? I can always read the excel using apache poi and build a html table and construct the email message but am trying to find if there is any simpler solution which using which I can attach the excel file contents inline just as we attach images inline in email.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler on doing this. Your first approach is correct. Read the excel, build a HTML table and send out the HTML email.

Comment: Thanks Wilts, Cant we inlcude excel attachments inline using MimeBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE)? I have tried it but it always ends up as a normal attachment. Not sure if am missing something.

Comment: How such "attachments" are displayed is up to the mail reader, and very few mail readers (if any) are going to display an Excel file inline, even if you give them the advice to do so.  HTML is the right answer.

Comment: Thats really a good point. Thanks Bill. I will go with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How about aspose API? though it is commercial.
Ref:[aspose excel to html](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Converting+Excel+Files+to+HTML)

```
//Specify the file path
String filePath = myDir + "Book1.xlsx";

//Specify the HTML Saving Options
HtmlSaveOptions save = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.HTML);

//Instantiate a workbook and open the template XLSX file
Workbook book = new Workbook(filePath);

//Save the HTML file
book.save(myDir + "output.html", save);
```